# XtraGrid Grouped with Summaries UI thread blocks on large data set

Tags: devexpress, grouping, summary, xtragrid

Using DevExpress XtraGrid 16.2 for grouping and aggregation.

What I wanted to do is to group by any column and then some of the numeric columns will show totals in the group row.

I have customized `BindingList<T>` for XtraGrid datasource where T is just POCO objects.

When I create a GridColumn that needs to show a summary I subsequently create GridSummaryItem for that column.

My summaries are shown in group row:
`gridView.OptionsBehavior.AlignGroupSummaryInGroupRow = DefaultBoolean.True;`

There is a market data feed that updates `BindingList<T>` quite frequently (every 5 sec) and then `BindingList<T>` fires of `OnListChnaged`.

When I have 300 items and grid is grouped by one column with market data turned on the lag is minimal and group summary recalculates without a problem.

When I have 1500 items the XtraGrid blocks UI thread and whole application locks up.

I used performance profiler dotTrace 2016.1.2 and it looks like DevExpress XtraGrid fires off `DoTypedSum` when `OnListChanged` is fired and recalculates summaries for each group row each time `BindingList<T>` is updated.

I have contacted DevExpress support and they told me that I have to calculate summaries myself and then paint them but isn't the whole point of their feature for them to do this?

Has anyone encountered this issue and has solutions to speed up the performance.

[image]

Comment: Would using Server Mode be a possibility for you? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2991

Comment: The updates are event driven. They are also tied to strongly typed dataset. When update is propagated to to the dataset it will raise an event which will trigger an update on `BindingList<T>` . So data flows from the server via dataset to the client with events raised.